# I have an error I know for sure, but I don't were

Tags: html, jquery

I create a maintenance table to add, edit, delete, and search, my problem is if i automate the adding the Table Row the search syntax is not working and if hard coded it the Table Row, it works but if i add a clone table row the search is not working for the cloned so how do i fix this.

here's the code for automate adding row

```js
var $ctrl_Name_p1 = $('[name^="ctrl_name_p1"]');
var $ctrl_Adname_p1 = $('[name^="ctrl_adname_p1"]');
var $ctrl_Name_p3 = $('[name^="ctrl_name_p3_"]');
var $ctrl_Adname_p3 = $('[name^="ctrl_adname_p3_"]');


$ctrl_Name_p1.on('change', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    search(this.value);
  }
});

$ctrl_Adname_p1.on('change', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    search(this.value);
  }
});

$ctrl_Name_p3.on('change', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    search(this.value);
  }
});

$ctrl_Adname_p3.on('change', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 3) {
    search(this.value);
  }
});

function search(name) {
  $.post(`/iworkflow/extend/index.php/go/post/live/app_ph_acs/maintenance/FindEmployee`, {
    'name': name
  }, function(emp) {
    $ctrl_Name_p1.val(emp["Name"]);
    $ctrl_Adname_p1.val(emp["Win Account"]);
    $ctrl_Name_p3.val(emp["Name"]);
    $ctrl_Adname_p3.val(emp["Win Account"]);
  }).always(function() {
    // Additional code can be added here for handling the result of the AJAX request
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0
  const addrowP1 = () => {
    var newrow = '';
    var therow = `
<tr class="plant1-row_${i}" data-plant1="">
<td class="p-0">
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext form-control-sm px-1 plant3-action-onchange" name="ctrl_area1_p1" placeholder="Input Areas">
</td>
<td class="p-0">
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext form-control-sm px-1 plant3-action-onchange" name="ctrl_adname_p1" placeholder="Search Adname">
</td>
<td class="p-0">
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext form-control-sm px-1 plant3-action-onchange" name="ctrl_name_p1" placeholder="Search name">
</td>
`;
    newrow += therow;
    $('#TableP1 tbody').append(newrow);
    i++
  }

  // Initial row addition
  addrowP1();

  // Event handler for dynamically adding rows
  $(document).on('click', '.btnAddRowP1', function() {
    addrowP1();
  });

  //
  var j = 0;
  const addrowP3 = () => {
    var newrow = '';
    var therow = `
<tr class="plant3-row_${j}" data-plant3="">
<td class="p-0">
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext form-control-sm px-1 plant3-action-onchange" name="ctrl_area1_p3" placeholder="Input Areas">
</td>
<td class="p-0">
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext form-control-sm px-1 plant3-action-onchange" name="ctrl_adname_p3" placeholder="Search Adname">
</td>
<td class="p-0">
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext form-control-sm px-1 plant3-action-onchange" name="ctrl_name_p3" placeholder="Search name">
</td>
`;
    newrow += therow;
    $('#TableP3 tbody').append(newrow);
    j++
  }

  // Initial row addition
  addrowP3();

  // Event handler for dynamically adding rows
  $(document).on('click', '.btnAddRowP3', function() {
    addrowP3();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-3">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item ml-2" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="t41-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#t41-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="t41-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">
<i class="fa-solid fa-building fa-fw"></i> Plant 1
</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ml-1" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link" id="t42-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#t42-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="t42-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">
<i class="fa-solid fa-building fa-fw"></i> Plant 3 & 4
</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade p-2 show active" id="t41-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t41-tab" tabindex="0">
      <!-- Plant 1 -->
      <table class="table table-sm table-bordered fs-10 w-100" id="TableP1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Area for Plant 1</th>
            <th>ADName / PH Account</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class=""></tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td contenteditable="false" colspan="99" class="text-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa-regular fa-plus text-success btnAddRowP1 px-3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Add Row"></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa-regular fa-trash text-danger btnDelRowP1 px-3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete Row"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade p-2" id="t42-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t42-tab" tabindex="0">
      <!-- Plant 3 & 4 -->
      <table class="table table-sm table-bordered fs-10 w-100" id="TableP3">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Area for Plant 3 & 4</th>
            <th>ADName / PH Account</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="">
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td contenteditable="false" colspan="99" class="text-right">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa-regular fa-plus text-success btnAddRowP3 px-3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Add Row"></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa-regular fa-trash text-danger btnDelRowP3 px-3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Delete Row"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so the search in the table, i search certain person in my database so I don't know where went wrong

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: sorry i put it accident

Comment: Hi, the input-boxes are added dynamically so you need to use event delegation on them to work just like you did for `$(document).on('click', '.btnAddRowP3',..`

Comment: Code works fine with `$(document).on('change', '[name^="ctrl_name_p"],[name^="ctrl_adname_p"]', function() {`  the problem is you're looking for `ctrl_adname_p3_*` but the name is `ctrl_adname_p3`  - so "p3_" doesn't match "p3"